# Вывод значения на сцену в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим, я хочу выводить значение на сцену в юнити.
Например у меня есть переменная second которая обновляется в функции update() и мне надо выводить ее на сцену, как это сделать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам потребуется использовать UI компонент *Text*. Создать на сцене объект с этим компонентом, расположить, где нужно, дать на него ссылку в скрипте и каждый кадр обновлять строковую информацию в его поле *.text*.

Подробнее [о компоненте в документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) (с примерами)
[Официальный видеоурок](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-text) по компоненту.
[Официальный видеоурок](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/displaying-score-and-text) по отображению теста и игрового счета.